# .NET Core worker - since enabling Docker Compose my service can't read IAM credentials from appsettings.json

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core, docker-compose, appsettings

I am building a small .NET Core worker service to read messages from an AWS SQS queue. To do this, it requires IAM credentials in the form of an access and secret key. I had originally been running this project as a docker container, and it has been working fine. I wanted to enable the ability to run this container multiple times, so multiple instances of the same service. I enabled Docker Compose in Visual Studio and it added the base docker compose YAML file to the project. Now when I try to run the solution in debug, I get the following error:

```
An exception of type 'Amazon.Runtime.AmazonServiceException' occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.dll but was not handled in user code: 'Unable to get IAM security credentials from EC2 Instance Metadata Service.'
```

I am assuming this is because somehow now the solution can't read the access and secret key from my appSettings.json but I'm unsure how to fix this.

Here is my DockerFile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["WorkerServiceDocker.csproj", ""]
RUN dotnet restore "./WorkerServiceDocker.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "WorkerServiceDocker.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "WorkerServiceDocker.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
RUN mkdir -p /app/logging
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WorkerServiceDocker.dll"]
```

Here is the docker compose file created by Visual Studio

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  workerservicedocker:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}workerservicedocker
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

The method that fails is:

```
public async void TriggerMessageGetAsync(string queueUrl, int pollingTime)
{
    var _messages = await GetMessagesAsync(queueUrl, pollingTime);
    if (_messages.Count == 0)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation($"No messages found.");
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (var message in _messages)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"Message {message.MessageId} received OK");
        }
    }
}
```

And my configuration is loaded from appSettings.json in the Program.cs

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Session.InstanceGuid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        File.Create("init.log").Close();
        var logWriter = new StreamWriter("init.log");
        logWriter.WriteLine("Assembly Path: " + Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location));
        logWriter.WriteLine($"Session Guid: {Session.InstanceGuid}");
        logWriter.WriteLine($"Container DateTime: {DateTime.Now}");
        logWriter.Dispose(); 
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
                services.AddSingleton<ILogger, Logger>(); // Using my own basic wrapper around NLog for the moment, pumped to CloudWatch.
                services.AddAWSService<IAmazonSQS>();
            });
}
```

When I run in debug using the 'Docker Compose' option, the output indicates that it has found AWS credentials?

```
  Found AWS options in IConfiguration
```

AWSSDK: Information: Found AWS options in IConfiguration
AWSSDK: Information: Found credentials using the AWS SDK's default credential search

I'm not sure what else to include with this question, but am hoping someone can assist. I am clearly missing some configuration or option that ensures the access and secret key can be read from my appSettings.json file. As I said, this was working fine when I was running it as a single docker container from my DockerFile.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see where you actually instruct AWS to use those credentials, so I will solve that as a likely problem.

First, your appsettings.json should be in this format for aws creds:

```
"AWS": {        
    "AccessKey": "abc",         
    "SecretKey": "xyz",         
    "Region": "ksjs"    
},
```

And then try this solution ( explicitly setting environment variables before you initialize the aws service)

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/issues/499#issuecomment-276142625